# Pattern in point-free combinator, how related to SKI calculus

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, pointfree, combinatory-logic

As an exercise, I converted the following combinator to point-free notation:

```
h f g x y z = f x (g y z)
```

with the usual convention of `f`, `g`, `h` as functions, and `x`, `y`, `z` as expressions. (This is not a homework problem, but just for fun and to see if I understand point-free conversions.)

After a lengthy manual rewriting process aided by `ghci`, I ended up with the following:

```
h = ((flip (.)) (flip (.)) . (flip (.))) . ((.)(.))
```

I noticed that `h` only consists of two combinators, "compose" `(.)` and "reverse compose" `flip (.)`. With this, the original combinator can be written succinctly as:

```
c = (.) -- compose
r = flip c -- "reverse compose"
h = ((r r) . r) . (c c)
   = c(c(r r)r)(c c)
```

The structure (number and order of) of "compose" and "reverse compose" operations seem to be somehow related to the structure of the original combinator.

I reckon this is directly related to combinatory logic and SKI calculus. My questions are thus:

1. Can somebody with more insight explain what's going on here: How is the structure of "compose" and "reverse compose" in the point-free combinator related to the structure of functions and expressions in the pointful combinator?
2. Can this be generalized to arbitrary combinators (i.e., number of functions, number of expressions, and their order is arbitrary)? More specifically, can every combinator be expression in terms of "compose" and "reverse compose", and is there a scheme to derive the combination of "compose" and "reverse compose" *directly* from the structure of the pointful combinator (i.e., without going through the complete rewrite process)? For instance, is it possible to *directly* derive the pointfree versions of `\ f g x y z -> (f x y) g z` just from looking at the function structure?
3. What's the name in combinatory logic for `c` and `r`?

**Update:**

It seems that `c` is the `B` combinator and `r` is `CB` from the [B, C, K, W system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system).  But I'd still be happy to get more insight into my questions, especially questions 1 and 2.

Comment: If a variable occurs more than once on the rhs then B and CB are no longer enough (needs eg S).  If a variable doesn't occur at all they are also not enough (needs eg K)

Comment: With regard to 2, bracket abstraction is a simple algorithm for SKI.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinators_B.2C_C) you can find the bracket transformation that augustss mentions (I think).

Comment: augustss: Very interesting, thanks. What would be a good introductory text to learn about combinator calculus?

Will: Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's usually easier to derive the definitions by direct manipulation in combinatory form:

```
h f g x y z = f x (g y z)
            = B(fx)(gy)z     -- B rule
            = B(B(fx))gyz    -- B rule
h f g x = B(B(fx))g          -- eta-contraction
        = BBB(fx)g           -- B rule
        = B(BBB)fxg          -- B rule
        = C(B(BBB)f)gx       -- C rule
h f = C(B(BBB)f)             -- eta-contraction
    = BC(B(BBB))f            -- B rule
h   = BC(B(BBB))             -- eta-contraction
 -- = B(B(CB(CB))(CB))(BB)   -- your expression
```

The types are the same, though my expression is shorter. Can this serve as a counterexample to whether the combinatory form should somehow follow the given definition? There is considerable freedom in how the rules are applied, so widely different forms can be derived. I don't think much insight can be arrived at from a given combinatory expression.

If anything, the combinators that appear in the final translation are more representative of the *derivation steps taken*, and those can be chosen freely among those that fit, at any given point.

For example, the following step is commonly taken in deriving your expression, evidently:

```
g(fx) = Bgfx = CBfgx 

B (B (CB(CB)) (CB)) (BB) f g x y z
   = B (CB(CB)) (CB) (BB f) g x y z
   = CB (CB) (CB (BB f)) g x y z     --   and here
   = CB (BB f) (CB g) x y z          --  here
   = CB g (BB f x) y z               -- here
   = BB f x (g y) z
   = B (f x) (g y) z
   = f x (g y z)
```

But if you prioritize your rules application and make it deterministic, you should always arrive at the same result -- which will depend on the order in which you apply the rules.

Comment: Manipulating the combinatory form is indeed a lot simpler than my pointful-to-pointfree conversion process (I had about three times as many intermediate steps.)

Bummer, however, that an explicit conversion still seems necessary. I was hoping that the combinator form's structure is in direct relation to the pointful form. If not in general, than at least for special cases such as `f_{0,n_0} f_{1,n_1} ... f_{K-1, n_{K-1}}`, where `f_{i,n} := f_i xi_0 xi_1 ... xi_{n-1}` (i.e., `K` functions `f_0, ..., f_K`, each with a variable number [xi_0, ..., xi_{n-1}] of mutually disjoint expressions).

Comment: it seems to be in direct relation to the transformation steps taken.